# MPPT solar charger for Lead Acid Battery

Tags: power, solar-cell, lead-acid, solar-energy, mppt

I've seen plenty of good MPPT (or similar to MPPT) chargers for solar panels, but they all seem to be made for lithium based batteries. Here's an example of what I've seen: https://www.adafruit.com/product/390.

I have a project where I'm planning on using a 12v 1.3Ah lead acid battery, and I was wondering if there was a good charger like the ones I've seen that will work with lead acid chemistry (I'm assuming that the Lipo/L-ion ones won't work with lead acid). Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the good MPPT chargers are for lead acid batteries.  In fact it's hard to find ones for lithium batteries from the reputable companies.
For example these guys:

https://www.morningstarcorp.com/compare-products/?product_01=5780&product_02=2580&product_03=2581